# Two jQuery dialogs on the same webpage have an issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a user control which has a jQuery dialog. jQuery dialog has iframe for opening the webpage, test1.aspx.  Also I have a webpage has jQuery dialog in which also dialog has iframe for opening the webpage, 'test2.aspx'.
These two dialog boxes works fine if the user control didn't in the same webpage. Once the two dialog boxes on the same page. The jQuery dialog on user control keeps showing the test2.aspx, not test1.aspx. Sometime the dialog position is under the link close to user control. The dialog is designed to open on the top.

There is the code snippet on user control:

```
 <a title="Edit" onclick="openBoxTest('test1.aspx?id=659333','test',650,310, 'dialog1'); return false">Edit</a>
   <div id="dialog1">  <iframe id="myIframe" src="" ></iframe></div>
```

There is the code snippet on webpage:

```
  <span onclick="openBoxTest('/test2.aspx?ID=652','test2',650,310, 'dialog2');  return false" >test2</span>"
 <div id="dialog2">  <iframe id="myIframe" src="" ></iframe></div>
```

There is the script to open the dialog box:

```
function openBoxTest(url, name, width, height,  divID) {    
var box = $('#' + divID);   
  box.dialog({
    autoOpen: false,    
    max_height: 'auto',        
    height: 'auto',      
    width: 'auto',
    title: name,
    modal: true,

    position: {
        my: 'top',
        at: 'top',
        of: window,
        collision: "flip"
    },
    create: function (event, ui) {
        $(event.target).parent().css('position', 'fixed');
    },


    open: function (ev, ui) {          
        $('#myIframe').css('height', height+60);
        $('#myIframe').css('width', width);
        $('#myIframe').attr('src', url);

    },
});

  box.dialog('open');
return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little hard to understand what you're describing, but my first guess would be your two iframes inside dialog1 and dialog2 both have the ID=myIframe.  If they are on the same page this could be your problem.